# Paginating text in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, pagination, textview

I am writing a simple text/eBook viewer for Android, so I have used a `TextView` to show the HTML formatted text to the users, so they can browse the text in pages by going back and forth. But my problem is that I can not paginate the text in Android.

I can not (or I don't know how to) get appropriate feedback from the line-breaking and page-breaking algorithms in which `TextView` uses to break text into lines and pages. Thus, I can not understand where the content ends in the actual display, so that I continue from the remaining in the next page. I want to find way to overcome this problem.

**If I know what is the last character painted on the screen, I can easily put enough characters to fill a screen, and knowing where tha actual painting was finished, I can continue at the next page. Is this possible? How?**

---

Similar questions have been asked several times on StackOverflow, but no satisfactory answer was provided. These are just a few of them:

- [How to paginate long text into pages in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825063/how-to-paginate-long-text-into-pages-in-android)
- [Ebook reader pagination issue in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25961614/ebook-reader-pagination-issue-in-android)
- [Paginate text based on rendered text size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24998573/paginate-text-based-on-rendered-text-size)

There was a single answer, which seems to work, but it is slow. It adds characters and lines until the page is filled. I don't think this is a good way to do page breaking:

- [How to break styled text into pages in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20204348/how-to-break-styled-text-into-pages-in-android)

Rather than this question, it happens that **[PageTurner eBook reader](http://www.pageturner-reader.org/)** does it mostly right, although it is somehow slow.

- https://github.com/nightwhistler/pageturner

[image: screenshot of PageTurner eBook reader]

---

PS: I am not confined to TextView, and I know line breaking and page breaking algorithms can be quite complex ([as in TeX](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002%2Fspe.4380111102)), so I am not looking for an optimal answer, but rather a reasonably fast solution that can be usable by the users.

---

**Update:** This seems to be a good start for getting the right answer:

[Is there a way of retrieving a TextView's visible line count or range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239356/is-there-a-way-of-retrieving-a-textviews-visible-line-count-or-range)

**Answer:** After completing text layout, it is possible to find out the visible text:

```
ViewTreeObserver vto = txtViewEx.getViewTreeObserver();
        vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                ViewTreeObserver obs = txtViewEx.getViewTreeObserver();
                obs.removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                height = txtViewEx.getHeight();
                scrollY = txtViewEx.getScrollY();
                Layout layout = txtViewEx.getLayout();

                firstVisibleLineNumber = layout.getLineForVertical(scrollY);
                lastVisibleLineNumber = layout.getLineForVertical(height+scrollY);

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

### NEW ANSWER

[*PagedTextView*](https://github.com/onikx/PagedTextView) library (in Kotlin) summarises the below lying algorithm by extending Android TextView. The [sample app](https://github.com/onikx/PagedTextApp) demonstrates the usage of the library.

### Setup

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.onikx:pagedtextview:0.1.3'
}
```

### Usage

```
<com.onik.pagedtextview.PagedTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

---

### OLD ANSWER

*The algorithm below implements text pagination in separation of TextView itself lacking simultaneous dynamic change of both the TextView attributes and algorithm configuration parameters.*

### Background

What we know about text processing within `TextView` is that it properly breaks a text by lines according to the width of a view. Looking at the [TextView's sources](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java) we can see that the text processing is done by the [Layout](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/Layout.java) class. So we can make use of the work the `Layout` class does for us and utilizing its methods do pagination.

### Problem

The problem with `TextView` is that the visible part of text might be cut vertically somewhere at the middle of the last visible line. Regarding said, we should break a new page when the last line that fully fits into a view's height is met.

### Algorithm

- We iterate through the lines of text and check if the line's `bottom` exceeds the view's height;
- If so, we break a new page and calculate a new value for the cumulative height to compare the following lines' `bottom` with (*see the implementation*). The new value is defined as `top` value (*red line in the picture below*) of the line that hasn't fit into the previous page + `TextView's` height.

[image]

### Implementation

```
public class Pagination {
    private final boolean mIncludePad;
    private final int mWidth;
    private final int mHeight;
    private final float mSpacingMult;
    private final float mSpacingAdd;
    private final CharSequence mText;
    private final TextPaint mPaint;
    private final List<CharSequence> mPages;

    public Pagination(CharSequence text, int pageW, int pageH, TextPaint paint, float spacingMult, float spacingAdd, boolean inclidePad) {
        this.mText = text;
        this.mWidth = pageW;
        this.mHeight = pageH;
        this.mPaint = paint;
        this.mSpacingMult = spacingMult;
        this.mSpacingAdd = spacingAdd;
        this.mIncludePad = inclidePad;
        this.mPages = new ArrayList<>();

        layout();
    }

    private void layout() {
        final StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(mText, mPaint, mWidth, Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, mSpacingMult, mSpacingAdd, mIncludePad);

        final int lines = layout.getLineCount();
        final CharSequence text = layout.getText();
        int startOffset = 0;
        int height = mHeight;

        for (int i = 0; i < lines; i++) {
            if (height < layout.getLineBottom(i)) {
                // When the layout height has been exceeded
                addPage(text.subSequence(startOffset, layout.getLineStart(i)));
                startOffset = layout.getLineStart(i);
                height = layout.getLineTop(i) + mHeight;
            }

            if (i == lines - 1) {
                // Put the rest of the text into the last page
                addPage(text.subSequence(startOffset, layout.getLineEnd(i)));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    private void addPage(CharSequence text) {
        mPages.add(text);
    }

    public int size() {
        return mPages.size();
    }

    public CharSequence get(int index) {
        return (index >= 0 && index < mPages.size()) ? mPages.get(index) : null;
    }
}
```

### Note 1

The algorithm works not just for `TextView` (`Pagination` class uses `TextView's` parameters in the implementation above). You may pass any set of parameters `StaticLayout` accepts and later use the paginated layouts to draw text on [`Canvas`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html)/[`Bitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html)/[`PdfDocument`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument.html).

You can also use `Spannable` as **`yourText`** parameter for different fonts as well as `Html`-formatted strings (*like in the sample below*).

### Note 2

When all text has the same font size, all lines have equal height. In that case you might want to consider further optimization of the algorithm by calculating an amount of lines that fits into a single page and jumping to the proper line at each loop iteration.

---

### Sample

The sample below paginates a string containing both `html` and `Spanned` text.

```
public class PaginationActivity extends Activity {
    private TextView mTextView;
    private Pagination mPagination;
    private CharSequence mText;
    private int mCurrentIndex = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pagination);

        mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

        Spanned htmlString = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.html_string));

        Spannable spanString = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.long_string));
        spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 24, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 24, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.MONOSPACE.getStyle()), 0, 24, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spanString.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 700, spanString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spanString.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 700, spanString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        spanString.setSpan(new StyleSpan(Typeface.MONOSPACE.getStyle()), 700, spanString.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        mText = TextUtils.concat(htmlString, spanString);

        mTextView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                // Removing layout listener to avoid multiple calls
                mTextView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                mPagination = new Pagination(mText,
                        mTextView.getWidth(),
                        mTextView.getHeight(),
                        mTextView.getPaint(),
                        mTextView.getLineSpacingMultiplier(),
                        mTextView.getLineSpacingExtra(),
                        mTextView.getIncludeFontPadding());
                update();
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.btn_back).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex > 0) ? mCurrentIndex - 1 : 0;
            update();
        });
        findViewById(R.id.btn_forward).setOnClickListener(v -> {
            mCurrentIndex = (mCurrentIndex < mPagination.size() - 1) ? mCurrentIndex + 1 : mPagination.size() - 1;
            update();
        });
    }

    private void update() {
        final CharSequence text = mPagination.get(mCurrentIndex);
        if(text != null) mTextView.setText(text);
    }
}
```

`Activity`'s layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_back"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_forward"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at my [demo project](https://github.com/AlexanderTolstykh/TextViewPagination).

The "magic" is in this code:

```
    mTextView.setText(mText);

    int height = mTextView.getHeight();
    int scrollY = mTextView.getScrollY();
    Layout layout = mTextView.getLayout();
    int firstVisibleLineNumber = layout.getLineForVertical(scrollY);
    int lastVisibleLineNumber = layout.getLineForVertical(height + scrollY);

    //check is latest line fully visible
    if (mTextView.getHeight() < layout.getLineBottom(lastVisibleLineNumber)) {
        lastVisibleLineNumber--;
    }

    int start = pageStartSymbol + mTextView.getLayout().getLineStart(firstVisibleLineNumber);
    int end = pageStartSymbol + mTextView.getLayout().getLineEnd(lastVisibleLineNumber);

    String displayedText = mText.substring(start, end);
    //correct visible text
    mTextView.setText(displayedText);
```

Comment: You could also eliminate the last word if it is incomplete so you don't cut words; also, if the textview is not scrollable, you could just use `getLineCount()` to get `lastVisibleLineNumber`. This needs to be wrapped in a `GlobalLayoutListener` using `getViewTreeObserver()` so that the `TextView` has a height before calculating.

Answer (score 4):

Surprisingly finding libraries for **Pagination** is difficult. I think it's better to use another Android UI element besides TextView. How about **WebView**?
An example @ [android-webview-example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/).
Code snippet:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);

String customHtml = "<html><body><h1>Hello, WebView</h1></body></html>";
webView.loadData(customHtml, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Note: This simply loads data onto a WebView, similar to a web browser. But let's not stop with just this idea. Add this UI to using pagination by [WebViewClient onPageFinished](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onPageFinished(android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String)) . Please read on SO link @ [html-book-like-pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636052/html-book-like-pagination).
Code snippet from one of the best answer by Dan:

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
   public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
   ...
      mWebView.loadUrl("...");
   }
});
```

Notes:

- The code loads more data upon page scroll.
- On the same webpage, there is a posted answer by Engin Kurutepe to set measurements for the WebView. This is necessary for specifing a page in pagination.

I have not implemented pagination but I think this is a good start and shows promise, should be fast. As you can see, there are developers that have implemented this feature.