# Pagination of HTML text in android without using webview

Tags: android, html, android-webview, textview

I have a long HTML text, I need to show it in paginated form in viewpager. [Following this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096884/1754982) I used `StaticLayout` for the same. The only problem with the solution is if there is a HTML tag which starts at previous page and ends at next page, it will not be reflected in next page.

Say:

```
"<~b> This is a very long sample text that need's to be paginated.<~/b>".
```

After pagination:

```
Page 1:- "<~b> This is a very long sample text"

Page 2:- " that need's to paginated.<~/b>"
```

Then the text on page 2 will not be bold as it is suppose to be.