# Display C code inside the Android App/ Android Studio

Tags: android, c, android-studio

I'm currently working on an android app to help my fellow classmates to learn C language. I'm pretty much done with the design and layout of the app, and have even managed to put explanation with example. But I really don't know how to display the C programs inside the app.

I've read about displaying HTML code and reading/displaying from a text file in raw folder but I don't think that'd prove helpful here. Plus I'm new to Java/Android Studio stuff so I request you all to post a bit detailed answer with little explanation.

I don't necessarily want the C code to be color highlighted or prettified, it would be enough if I could just somehow display it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837840/paginating-text-in-android/32096884#32096884

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to achieve this would be with storing the code in a file ( http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html ) and reading from there every time the user opens the activity where the code can be seen.

Remember :

1. The permissions :

   ```
   <manifest ...>
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
   </manifest>
   ```
2. I recommend saving the files in the internal storage. This way, when the user uninstalls the app, the files are deleted. You can do something like this to read :

   ```
   File dir = getFilesDir();
   File file = new File(dir, "File.txt");

   try {
       //Attaching BufferedReader to the FileInputStream by the help of InputStreamReader
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new
               File(getFilesDir()+File.separator+"File.txt")));
       String inputString;

       s = "";
       //Reading data line by line and storing it into the stringbuffer
       while ((inputString = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

           s+=inputString + "\n";

       }

       bufferedReader.close();

   } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

And this to write :

```
    try {
            FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("File.txt", Context.MODE_APPEND);

            for (int l = 0;l<=10;l++) {
                fos.write("something".getBytes());
                fos.write("\n".getBytes());
            }

            fos.close();

            //display file saved message

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

See more details in the link provided. Happy coding!

Comment: Well I somehow managed to do what was suggested (your answer didn't work though, I had to look for another way to achieve the same), but now I want to turn that piece of code into **a function/method** so that I can call it from different activities and achieve a text view that displays the content of a particular file. Now I know the id and file are going to change for every text view so I think I need to pass those as arguments to the function/method , right? So will someone please help me achieve that (if it's attainable).