# How to work with big HTML String?

Tags: java, android, html

I want to get an HTML from a web page, remove some tags from the code and display it using a TextView... But those HTMLs are too big to be temporaly stored into a String...

When I try this way:

```
String html = "myBigHTML";
myTextView.setText(fromHtml(html));
```

compiler says `error: constant string too long`

If I put the html into a .txt and try this way:

```
InputStream is = getAssets().open("html.txt");

tvTeste.setText(fromHtml(convertStreamToString(is)));

public static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) throws Exception {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    reader.close();
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It works but the app gets soooo slow, almost freezes... And also, if I store it in a .txt I couldn't work with the tags...

**.:: EDIT ::.**

My `onCreate()` method as asked...

```
private TextView tvTeste;
private InputStream is;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_frequencia);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    tvTeste = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTeste);

    try {
        is = getAssets().open("html.txt");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    String strLine;

    List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
            stringList.add(strLine);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    tvTeste.setText(fromHtml(TextUtils.join("",stringList)));
}
```

Comment: In addition to the accepted answer you may find an alternative solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837840/paginating-text-in-android/32096884#32096884)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try this: each line of HTML text is a String. Each String is inside a List of String.

So, some **pseudocode**:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

while (htmlHandler.next()) {
   stringList.add(fromHtml(htmlHandler.readLine()));
}

myTextView.setText(joinStringArray(stringList));
```

Where `joinStringArray` uses a `StringBuilder` to produce a single big String object.
Basically you shouldn't read the entire web page, but you should read it sequentially.

Comment: I've done it using `TextUtils.join("",list)`... It works but the application gets extremely slow also

Comment: Mmmh but how do you load the list?

Comment: It's loaded at `onCreate()` method... Maybe I could put some "Loading dialog" on it?

Comment: Well for sure a loading message or icon is perfectly fine. Can you post the onCreate() code? I'd like to see how you did it,if possible.

Comment: OK, as I thought you are still reading from the text file. How do you produce the text file? Instead of outputting to the. txt, output to the List. I'm at the gym so I'm using the phone. When I come home I'll give you an example.

Comment: Alright... Actually, I didn't make the code that creates the .txt yet... I can make a code to push the web page's HTML to the list, directly... But I will also need to get it from .txt files sometimes in my project

Comment: If you are able to push it into the List, that's the best solution

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna do that then... But the "most viewed" pages will be locally stored in the app, using a .txt... So this method will also be used... Thank you!

Comment: Remember that there are standard ways to cache pages.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

Another point to mark. You should avoid any time consuming process that blocks the activity. try the same using, for example an AsyncTask.
Please check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html