# How to implement lazy rendering/pagination for an Android TextView

Tags: java, android, performance, pagination

I have an Android app that offers syntax highlighting for source code files. It's performing very poorly for large files [such as this](https://github.com/jamesqo/1_LanguageTesting/blob/master/100000Chars.java) and freezing the UI for 10+ seconds. I have profiled my app and a method out of my control appears to be taking up a lot of time on the main thread. I would like to implement lazy rendering / 'pagination' so that instead of coloring the whole file when the user loads it, I only color what the user sees at first, and color in uniformly-sized chunks as (s)he scrolls down. What are some approaches I can take to implementing this? Thanks.

Comment: Can [Paginating text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837840/paginating-text-in-android/32096884#32096884) be a starting point?