# How to fit text into StaticLayout with fixed width and height in Android?

Tags: android, staticlayout

I'm trying to draw text using `Canvas` and have found that using `StaticLayout` would take care of the line breaks automatically. I also want to limit its height so that when text is too long it would be ellipsized, but the size of text container is dynamic. I can easily apply the width to `StaticLayout`, but cant find a way to do height.

I tried to utilize `TextUtils.ellipsize()`, but having issue to get the spacing between lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PerracoLabs has the right answer but, as CheokYanCheng stated, the calculation of the maximum number of lines is off (although it may yield the correct result many if not most of the time).

*A maximum height cannot be specified for a *StaticLayout* except indirectly by specifying the maximum number of lines. Ellipsis is tied to the maximum line count anyway, so determining the maximum number of lines for a specific height to back into a solution is the way to go. So, how do we determine the appropriate maximum line count so that a fixed-size StaticLayout with ellipsis can be created as PerracoLabs has explained.?*

If the text has no spans that effect the height any of the lines of text then a simply calculation can determine the maximum number of lines that will fit into a *StaticLayout* before ellipsis.

The following Kotlin function will determine how many lines of text will fit into a view that has a fixed height and width. It is assumed that each line of a *StaticLayout* has a set height (no height-effecting spans). The top line has the same height of other lines but it is augmented by a top padding. The bottom line has a bottom padding added to it.

```
private fun getMaxLines(maxHeight: Int): Int {  
    // Build a dummy StaticLayout to get the internal measurements.  
    return makeStaticLayout("", width, 1).run {  
        val lineHeight = getLineBottom(0) - getLineTop(0) + topPadding - bottomPadding  
        (maxHeight - topPadding - bottomPadding) / lineHeight  
}
```

However, if the text contains a span that changes the height of one or more lines then the only way to calculate the maximum number of lines is through the creation of the static layout that holds the entire text (no ellipsis) followed by an inspection of the lines within the layout to determine how many complete lines have fit. A new *StaticLayout* can then be created with the calculated maximum lines determined from the inspection.

The following Kotlin function will calculate the maximum lines by inspecting the *StaticLayout* for the last full line that is present.

```
private fun getMaxLinesByInspection(staticLayout: StaticLayout, maxHeight: Int): Int {
    var line = staticLayout.lineCount - 1
    while (line >= 0 && staticLayout.getLineBottom(line) >= maxHeight) {
        line--
    }
    return line + 1
}
```

I have posted a [small project](https://github.com/Cheticamp/StaticLayoutFixedSize) on GitHub as a demonstration.

Here is a screen shot of the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You (and @[Cheok Yan Cheng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/72437/cheok-yan-cheng)) might try to make use of [PagedTextView](https://github.com/onikx/PagedTextView). The view is intended for [Paginating text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096884/3290339).

The view partially solves the problem, i.e. reacts to dynamic size changes. As to text ellipsizing, you might achieve this by customising the [algorithm](https://github.com/onikx/PagedTextView/blob/master/lib/src/main/java/com/onik/pagedtextview/PagedTextView.kt#L129) I've used for measuring text in height.

Comment: @Cheok Yan Cheng, do you need an assistance with the algorithm customisation?