# How to arrange texts dynamically in TextView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout

I'm building an android app which I have to handle and arrange lots of texts in multiple pages(using Fragments) with margin numbers or dots dynamically like this Dictionary app[image] :[image]

Comment: [Paginating text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31837840/3290339)