# Is there a library for showing long text in one single TextView with different formatting?

Tags: android, textview, text-formatting

E.g. similar looking to what apps like Fabulous are doing.
My use case it that I have a longer text stored online, which should then be retrieved and displayed. So I cannot style every single one with different TextViews and would like to have something with tags or so inside.

Maybe something [like that](https://chiuki.github.io/advanced-android-textview/#/16)? But doesn't seem to be usable as a library.

[image]

I have looked for something in the [Android must have libraries](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Must-Have-Libraries) but no results.

Comment: Why not use a WebView?

Comment: Would [Paginating text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31837840/3290339) fit your need?

Comment: Thanks guys, your suggestions led me to some interesting searches, especially @Onik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found something really close to what I wanted with this library: [SRML: "String Resource Markup Language"](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/4672)

[image]