# Split single textview into multiple pages

Tags: android, text, pagination, textview

I have a single `textview` which I am trying to split it into multiple pages kind of pagination. Is it possible in single `textview`? If so please tell me how to do it.

Comment: Can you explain a little better what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @LucaNicoletti I am trying to show `textview` like ebupreader having page wise

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Paginating text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31837840/paginating-text-in-android)