# Android TextView - determine if multiline text will fit into the TextView

Tags: android, fonts, textview

I have a TextView with specific font and font size set. I want to determine if a multiline text will fit into this TextView (the TextView is set to match_parent for both width and height).
Is there any reasonable way of doinf it?

Thanks

Comment: Yes. You could make use of the solution I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096884/3290339).

Answer (score 1):

You can measure the bounds of your text using this approach:

```
String yourText = "...";
Rect bound = new Rect();
textView.getPaint().getTextBounds(yourText , 0, yourText.length(), bounds);
```

Then you can get width and height of text for the giving textview:

```
bounds.width() or bounds.height();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your TextView inside a ScrollView, you will know it will fit 100% :)

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Ty Juan" />
</ScrollView>
```