# Extremely large string in TextView?

Tags: android, string, text, textview, large-data

How to show very large string (let's say 25 MB or more maybe even 50MB) without any paragraphs or spaces in a `TextView`? There no TextRecyclerView in Android. If you directly try to load into `TextView` you just get ANR straight away.

If you split in chucks and put it in `RecycleView` in a different screens and rotation the text will be look different. It should behave as single `TextView`.

For simplicity our file stored in raw or assets folder and called `large_string.txt`.

How to solve such problem and show this huge string with scrolling smoothly without any lag?

Comment: Have you considered [Paginating text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31837840/3290339)?