# Swipe left/right TextView like a book and show more TextView contents

Tags: android, android-studio, textview, swipe, epub

I wanna implement a EpubReader application.

I have a TextView that contains HTML contents. 
How can i show other contents after last line in TextView using swipe to left(like a book)?

I've tried  to split the contents using ViewPager and a Fragment(with TextView) and show it, But it's not a good idea, Because the app includes a few buttons to change the font type, font size, Highlighting text. So when the font size increases, the end of the text may be removed from the current page and moved to the next page.

I want to do it with just one TextView. And after swiping to the left, display the rest of the text in the same TextView.

Comment: TextView does not support rendering an entire book's worth of text in a single TextView (not in a remotely performant manner, at least), nor does it support nearly enough HTML to be an effective ePUB renderer.

Comment: [Paginating text in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32096884/3290339).

Comment: I have a dynamic text. The font size and type can be changed. What do you suggest for pagination?